# Which HTTP method to use to verify user entry?

Tags: ajax, rest, http

I have a text box whose value is verified by the server upon any kind of change (whenever the user types, deletes, pastes, etc) . This verification is done by an AJAX request over HTTP to the server.

Which HTTP method should be used in this verification process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POST`. The client is requesting that the server create a spell-checked document.

Comment: Thank you Eric! Any idea why this question was down-voted? It seems reasonable to me,,,,